# Unsure what SQL query is attempting to do

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on some inherited code, and am having an issue with an SQL Query within it. The query is as follows.

```
Select distinct 
    g.scriptid,
    g.procedurename,
    h.parameters,
    g.scriptname,
    h.usercode,
    h.facility,
    h.recid,
    cast((cast(recid as varchar) + '.' +  Right('0000' + cast(scriptgennum as varchar), 4)) as decimal(10,4)) as 'scriptrecid',
    scriptgennum+1 as 'scriptgennum',
    h.generated,
    h.runinterval,
    case 
        when runinterval = 'M' then dateadd(month,1,convert(varchar(10),h.nextrundate,120)) 
        when runinterval = 'Q' then dateadd(month,3,convert(varchar(10),h.nextrundate,120)) 
        when runinterval = 'W' then dateadd(week,1,convert(varchar(10),h.nextrundate,120))  
        when runinterval = '0' then NULL end as 'nextrundate',
    convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120) as currentrundate,
    scripttype

    from PATIENTLETTERS_SCRIPTHIST h join PATIENTLETTERS_SCRIPTS g on
        g.scriptid = h.scriptid where 
        h.status = 'Y' 
        and (([runinterval] = 'M'
            and (convert(varchar(10),nextrundate,120) = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
            and datepart(day,getdate()) = 5
            and (datediff(month,convert(varchar(10),h.lastrundate,120),convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)) = 1)
            or lastrundate is null))
        or ([runinterval] = 'Q'
            and (convert(varchar(10),nextrundate,120) = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
            and datepart(weekday,getdate()) = 0
            and (datediff(month,convert(varchar(10),h.lastrundate,120),convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)) = 3)
            or lastrundate is null))
        or ([runinterval] = 'W'
            and (convert(varchar(10),nextrundate,120) = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
            and datepart(day,getdate()) = 5
            and (datediff(week,convert(varchar(10),h.lastrundate,120),convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)) = 1)
            or lastrundate is null)) 
        or ([runinterval] = 'O'
            and (convert(varchar(10),nextrundate,120) = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
            and (datepart(weekday,getdate()) = 0))
            or lastrundate is null))
```

I know that it is trying to select the specific columns listed from `PATIENTLETTERS_SCRIPTHIST` and `PATIENTLETTERS_SCRIPTS`. The part of the query that has me confused are the lines like these:

```
            and (([runinterval] = 'M'
            and (convert(varchar(10),nextrundate,120) = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
            and datepart(day,getdate()) = 5
            and (datediff(month,convert(varchar(10),h.lastrundate,120),convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)) = 1)
```

If someone can explain what those lines are actually doing I would greatly appreciate any help. I can see that it wants to make sure that the run interval is 'M', and it looks like its trying to match up the current date to the day in stored in the database in the 4th line, but the 2nd and 3rd lines are still a complete mystery.

Comment: The 2nd line simply compares the nextrundate with the current date .120 is a format to display date in the form yyyy-mm-dd . The 3nd line  retrieves the day for the current date and that should match with 5 .It seems to me that  you need values only for the 5th day for the month

Comment: Those lines are designed to produce the occasional odd result by calling `GetDate()` repeatedly in hopes of catching the date changing.  It's generally a good idea to capture the current date/time in a variable and use that value throughout a query or stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for items set to run **monthly**, where the next run date is **today**, and today is the **5th** of the month, and it's been exactly one month since the item was **last run**.

- More info on [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)
- and [DATEPART](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx)

Comment: That's what I was thinking but just couldn't fully convince myself. Thank you. Solves part 1 of who knows how many to fix this project and get it working. If I posted all of the code you'd probably think it was written by someone who just finished reading the first chapter of PHP/SQL for Dummies.

Answer (score 1):

This code is looking for items that have a `runinterval = 'M'`

```
line 1 - [runinterval] = 'M'
```

and the `nextrundate` is equal to the current date (`getdate()`), the dates are being [converted](http://anubhavg.wordpress.com/2009/06/11/how-to-format-datetime-date-in-sql-server-2005/) to a varchar with the same formatting.

```
line 2 - and (convert(varchar(10),nextrundate,120) = convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)
```

and the current date has a day equal to 5.  Meaning that the date would have to be June 5, July 5, etc

```
line 3 - and datepart(day,getdate()) = 5
```

and the difference between the month of the `lastrundate` and the current date (`getdate()`) is equal to 1

```
line 4 - (datediff(month,convert(varchar(10),h.lastrundate,120),convert(varchar(10),getdate(),120)) = 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The second line converts `nextrundate` and the current date to 'YYYY-MM-DD' format using style 120 ([More details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)) then checks that they're the same,  so only rows where `nextrundate` is today.

The third line just checks that today is the 5th day of the month.  For instance:
`SELECT DATEPART(DAY, '2012-07-05')` returns 5.